# maven 3 archetype:generate Error

Tags: java, build, maven-3, maven-archetype

I followed the instructions on Apache Maven site and it works fine but during the tutorial i was asked to type in the below code, what does that mean and why does it keeps throwing me a build error?. However i tried to type single line everytime and also everything together nothing makes a difference. Could some one please help me interpret this one and how to get started with maven without errors?

Thanks a lot,
SS

```
 mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

error below [UPDATE] , Updated the title also.

[image]

Comment: Hi Vivin,  I updated the post with the error. However I tried 3 times to upload the pic, but not sure how to maximize it, i tried to increase the font and resolution but still the picture seems small in the post, you could download it and see. Thanks

Comment: Can you just copy and paste the error, not as an image?  Also, include a link to the instructions you are trying to follow? Thanks.

Comment: What version of maven is this? When I run the command, I get a list of archetypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. I found the problem, i was behind a proxy and did not know the proxy feature in maven and as it was running for the first time, it was trying to download some plugins and failed. now i fixed it and it works as it should.

Thanks,
SS